# django wont work with python3.3.3

Tags: django

Hello I recently installed the django on my Mac OS X 10.9 using the `pip install Django`.
The installation was successful, now my python3.3.3 is installed in the following directory:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages

Inside this directory there is a directory for django so I am assuming that the installation was success on python 3.

The problem arise when I am trying the following procedure:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

The above command creates with success the directory with the files
Then on this command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

or

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

The error is:

```
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

Moreover, I do find a solution but wont work. Was to change the first comment of the file django-admin.py to link the compiler to the correct version of python, which was fine, but the problem is the same.

Any help?

Comment: You should be using a virtualenv.

Comment: On the official website of the django is using the pip install. What should I do with the virtualenv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this tutorial on python development on OSX: http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/

Virtualenv allows you to create sandboxes where you can install different python versions and python libraries without interfering with other virtual environments or with your system python version/libraries.

Your specific problem though, seems to be that Django was not added to your system path, so python doesn't know where to find the django files. It can be risky to add new things to your system path because it could end up conflicting with existing libraries.

If you use virtualenv, each environment will have its own "system" path and the python executable in that environment will know where to find the django files.